# Using Google Script to authenticate an API call

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

This is my first attempt at JavaScript using Google Script and I've hit a brick wall.

I'm after some help in using Google Scripts to grab data from an API. The API requires authentication for some of the functions and I'm having trouble getting it to work.

Below is the code to get the balance from an account on a crypto trading site:

```
function Hash() {

  var SystemTimeMilli = Date.now()   //This line will get the current time in milliseconds

  var accountBalInputString = '/account/balance' + '\n' + SystemTimeMilli +'\n';           //This line builds the string needed to be encrypted

  var PrivateKey = 'bEDtDJnW0y/Ll4YZitxb+D5sTNnEpQKH67EJRCmQCqN9cvGiB8+IHzB7HjsOs3mSlxLmu4aiPDRpe9anuWzylw=='    //Sample private key (I know I need to use my own)

  var BTCsignature = Utilities.computeHmacSignature(Utilities.MacAlgorithm.HMAC_SHA_512, accountBalInputString, PrivateKey, Utilities.Charset.UTF_8); //This line encrypts the above string using the above key

  BTCsignature = Utilities.base64Encode(BTCsignature); //This converts the output of the above encryption to a base64 format

  var BTCbalanceParams = {
'Accept' : 'application/json',
'Accept-Charset' : 'UTF-8',
'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
'apikey' : 'bbr34267-dfgh-4pop-90ty-cdc9f4156a37', //another made up example
'timestamp' : SystemTimeMilli,
'signature' : BTCsignature
  };

  var BTCbalance = 
  UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.btcmarkets.net/account/balance', BTCbalanceParams);
```

The instructions provided by the website to use their API authentication can be found here: https://github.com/BTCMarkets/API/wiki/Authentication.

I keep getting 
`Returned Data from BTC: {"success":false,"errorCode":1,"errorMessage":"Authentication failed."}`

and I've tried everything I can think of.

I'm assuming the Date.now() gets the time in milliseconds to UTC time and I am also assuming the API wants the time in the same format (although I have tried manipulating it to be correct to my local time).

Otherwise is there anything obvious I'm doing incorrectly or worth trying?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it reads how to use API from the URL that you showed, `BTCbalanceParams` has to be defined as a header. And method is GET. When this is reflected to your script, the modified script is as follows.

### Modified script :

```
function Hash() {
  var SystemTimeMilli = Date.now()   //This line will get the current time in milliseconds
  var accountBalInputString = '/account/balance' + '\n' + SystemTimeMilli +'\n';           //This line builds the string needed to be encrypted
  var PrivateKey = 'bEDtDJnW0y/Ll4YZitxb+D5sTNnEpQKH67EJRCmQCqN9cvGiB8+IHzB7HjsOs3mSlxLmu4aiPDRpe9anuWzylw=='    //Sample private key (I know I need to use my own)
  var BTCsignature = Utilities.computeHmacSignature(Utilities.MacAlgorithm.HMAC_SHA_512, accountBalInputString, PrivateKey, Utilities.Charset.UTF_8); //This line encrypts the above string using the above key
  BTCsignature = Utilities.base64Encode(BTCsignature); //This converts the output of the above encryption to a base64 format
  var BTCbalanceParams = {
    'Accept' : 'application/json',
    'Accept-Charset' : 'UTF-8',
    'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
    'apikey' : 'bbr34267-dfgh-4pop-90ty-cdc9f4156a37', //another made up example
    'timestamp' : SystemTimeMilli,
    'signature' : BTCsignature
  };

  // Added
  var params = {
    method: "get",
    headers: BTCbalanceParams,
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  };
  var BTCbalance = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.btcmarkets.net/account/balance', params); // Modified
}
```

### Note :

- About each parameters, I couldn't confirm whether those are correct. So this modified script supposes that those parameters are correct.
- `Date.now()` retrieves a time with milliseconds. It seems that this API is also required this.

If this was not useful for you, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thanks... those additions helped. I'm still getting an error but it's a different one now:  
'Returned Data from BTC: {"success":false,"errorCode":5,"errorMessage":" error occured while trying to get balance."}'

I might have to contact the owners of the API to get help from here on in.

Comment: @JayDough I'm sorry for the inconvenience. For example, how about modifying from ``/account/balance`` to ``/order/history``? The URL you showed uses this. I'm sorry I cannot test this.

Comment: Thanks Tanaike, 

I've played around a bit and I feel like the problem is with the way Google Script is computing the HMAC SHA512. I'm going to create a new question on StackOverflow detailing the new issue.

Comment: @JayDough Thank you for the additional information. I'm sorry I couldn't notice about that.

Comment: @JayDough Was your problem solved? If it's so, I'm glad.